# Trigger automatically run at specific time

Tags: sql, triggers

I want to create a trigger that will work if the time is reached.

For example:

> I inserted data on 07:00:00,
>   after 60 minutes this trigger should be run automatically.

Comment: what rdbms are you using? seems like you need a scheduled job and not a trigger.

Comment: i didn't use rdbms. by the way i'm new in SQL i just want to learn this trick @ZoharPeled

Comment: Sql triggers are triggered by a change of the data in the table. If you need to schedule some action, a trigger is probably not the best way to do it, but a schedule jobs. Different databases use different sql dialects - i.e Oracle use pl/sql, Sql server use t-sql. So, to answer your question, we need to know what database you want the solution for.

Comment: You use an RDBMS, and if you don't know you do then you should learn. SQL Server, MySQL, and Oracle are some examples of an RDBMS.

Comment: clear some of my doubts for an answer.
1. Do you want to run a stored procedure at certain time.
2. Are you using licence or express edition of MS SQL.

Answer (score -2):

In `SQL Server` RDBMS, You can use `WAITFOR DELAY` to issue wanted delay in trigger creation.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerA ON dbo.Table1 AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE AS
BEGIN
    WAITFOR DELAY '00:60:00'    -- Wait for 60 minutes

    -- What you want to do after 60 minutes delay
    -- e.g:
    --INSERT Table2(col1, col2)
    --VALUES(1, 'a')
END
```

So, after each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` or `DELETE`, this trigger will execute what ever after `WAITFOR DELAY`.